# Allow Admin to Make other Admin Users Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, admin

Is there a technique to allow an admin user to mark another user as admin from a webform with Rails?

I thought Hartl had a Railscast on the topic, but I couldn't find it.

I was looking to create my first admin user on the command line, then have the ability to visit `/users/3/edit` while an admin and be able to click a checkbox, enabling the third user to be an admin.  Obviously, a non admin would not have this ability.

I'm using devise, so I understand I'll have to setup up the CRUD operations for the users, but I can't think of how to limit the ability to pass a parameter based on the current user's role.

Rails 4.0.2

Devise 3.2.2

Ruby 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use cancan gem https://github.com/ryanb/cancan. Look at this http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan. I thing it what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I think cancan only authorizes users once they have been assigned a role.  I want to limit who can assign a role to another user.  In that example, anyone can makes themselves an admin. I want only admins to be able to make other users admins.

Comment: why not - with cancan you can define custom actions. Look here https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Custom-Actions

Comment: You're right.  Never considered doing that.  And the parameter thing I remembered was mentioned in that page: https://github.com/ryanb/trusted-params.  Thanks!